# The best way to share state between reducers (redux toolkit)

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware, redux-toolkit

I am on stage of planning structure of application. It is my first react app.
Application has several state slices and some global states which affect other slices.
I am looking for the best way to make relation between slices.
My first thought is middleware.

For example:

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer, // { posts: [] }
    user: userReducer // { blocked: true }
  },
  middleware: [userValidation]
})
```

I want to disable adding posts if user is blocked. Should I use middleware for this?

```js
export default const userValidation = store => next => action => {

    const { user } = store.getState()

    if (action.type === 'posts/add' && user.blocked) {
        store.dispatch(someWarning())
    } else {
        next()
    }
}
```

I am afraid there will be very much middlewares which will have too much logic and conditions. Also I'm worried about performance. Is it good way?

Comment: A simpler way might be to do it at the component level. If the user is blocked, simply do not dispatch the "posts/add" action to begin with and have the button greyed out.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie I want to solve this at the business logic level. What if it is console application?

Answer (score 1):

### What's my point of view?

I think the backend should take care of authorization, backend should never trust the frontend and double check (why if a blocked user finds a way of sending the request?).

### What should you take care of?

I think you only should hide the button/form that fires the dispatch action. In the case a blocked user finds a way of sending the request, there will come back **401 (Unauthorized)** code response from backend.

### Real word example?

Look how StackOverflow handles vote action, it allows you to click on the arrow up of your own post, sends the request, the backend validates it and sends the response `You can't vote for your own post`.

[image]

### What if there are other components with other actions that depend on user status?

Well, let's suppose you have `PostComponent` and `CommentComponent` and you want to hide the action of posting and commenting if the user is blocked.

I would recommend that the components not to know something about the user, instead they should have some props like `canAddNewPost` and `canAddNewComment` that will be defined on render like so:

```
<PostComponent canAddNewPost={!user.isBlocked} />
// ...
<CommentComponent canAddNewComment={!user.isBlocked} />
```

Then in the components you can use that prop to decide what blocks to show or hide from the user. Or use that to validate the dispatch, for example:

```
{canAddNewPost ? <AddNewPostForm /> : null}
```

Or

```
if (!canAddNewPost) {
    store.dispatch(someWarning())
}
```

I hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it is helpfull, but I wrote earlier in comments that I want to solve this at the business logic level without views. Sorry, it is not the best example (about user/auth). The main question is how to make relations between slices and should I make a lot of middlewares?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing requiring you to make several slices, especially when you want to use the data from one slice into another one. So you could have only one slice containing both the user and post info, and then it's trivial to implement what you want.

Another solution is to use Redux-Thunk, as you can then look at the whole state and decide whether to continue with the action. A custom middleware as you wrote would be basically reinventing Redux-Thunk.

Comment: What if there are many reducers who has to know about user? Should I make a single reducer with hundred actions?

Comment: You can have several reducers looking at the same slice, so you can still split your reducer.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `createSlice({ reducers: { ...userReducer, ...postsReducer }})`

Comment: No, I mean `const reducer = (state, action) => userReducer(postsReducer(state, action), action)`. A reducer is just a function, you're free to construct it out of smaller function the way you want.

Comment: I see, thanks. It looks tough, imho :)

Answer (score 1):

According to @GuillaumeBrunerie answer, I can use thunk action creator:

```js
export const addPostWithValidation = payload => (dispatch, getState) => {
    getState().user.isBlocked
        ? dispatch(someWarning())
        : dispatch(addPost(payload))
}
```

I think it is good way, isn't it?